# Storm topology shuts down in Local cluster after running for few seconds

Tags: apache-storm

I have a very basic topology. Starting with KafkaSpout, it has 3 bolts. First bolt is CassandraWriterBolt to write data in Cassandra, remaining 2 other bolts read old data from Cassandra create another set of data by using new and old data and again insert that data into Cassandra.

I am running that topology in LocalCluster during development. It runs for few seconds and then it starts shutting down worker, executor etc. Finally it fails with Cassandra driver related exception -

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not send request, session is closed
    at com.datastax.driver.core.SessionManager.execute(SessionManager.java:696) ~[cassandra-driver-core-3.6.0.jar:na]

Other logs are -

```
[er Executor - 1] o.a.s.s.org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper   : Session: 0x100166ad36d0024 closed
[.0/0.0.0.0:2000] o.a.s.s.o.a.z.server.NIOServerCnxn       : Unable to read additional data from client sessionid 0x100166ad36d0024, likely client has closed socket
[.0/0.0.0.0:2000] o.a.s.s.o.a.z.server.NIOServerCnxn       : Closed socket connection for client /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:63890 which had sessionid 0x100166ad36d0024
[- 1-EventThread] o.a.s.s.org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn  : EventThread shut down for session: 0x100166ad36d0024
[tor-Framework-0] o.a.s.s.o.a.c.f.i.CuratorFrameworkImpl   : backgroundOperationsLoop exiting
[:0 cport:2000):] o.a.s.s.o.a.z.s.PrepRequestProcessor     : Processed session termination for sessionid: 0x100166ad36d0021
[er Executor - 4] o.a.s.s.org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper   : Session: 0x100166ad36d0021 closed
[.0/0.0.0.0:2000] o.a.s.s.o.a.z.server.NIOServerCnxn       : Unable to read additional data from client sessionid 0x100166ad36d0021, likely client has closed socket
[.0/0.0.0.0:2000] o.a.s.s.o.a.z.server.NIOServerCnxn       : Closed socket connection for client /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:63885 which had sessionid 0x100166ad36d0021
[- 4-EventThread] o.a.s.s.org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn  : EventThread shut down for session: 0x100166ad36d0021
[      SLOT_1027] org.apache.storm.ProcessSimulator        : Begin killing process 1347f01d-7982-4141-9b9d-cac65a6e703d
[      SLOT_1027] org.apache.storm.daemon.worker.Worker    : Shutting down worker forex-topology-1-1577152204 517f3306-5ad3-433b-82e1-b2d031779f0b 1027
[      SLOT_1027] org.apache.storm.daemon.worker.Worker    : Terminating messaging context
[      SLOT_1027] org.apache.storm.daemon.worker.Worker    : Shutting down executors
[      SLOT_1027] o.a.storm.executor.ExecutorShutdown      : Shutting down executor __system:[-1, -1]
[xecutor[-1, -1]] org.apache.storm.utils.Utils             : Async loop interrupted!
[      SLOT_1027] o.a.storm.executor.ExecutorShutdown      : Shut down executor __system:[-1, -1]
[      SLOT_1027] o.a.storm.executor.ExecutorShutdown      : Shutting down executor pairStrengthAccumulator:[8, 8]
[-executor[8, 8]] org.apache.storm.utils.Utils             : Async loop interrupted!
[      SLOT_1027] o.a.s.cassandra.executor.AsyncExecutor   : shutting down async handler executor
[      SLOT_1027] o.a.s.c.client.impl.DefaultClient        : Try to close connection to cluster: cluster2
```

Following logs can be seen for 40 times -

```
[           main] o.a.storm.zookeeper.ClientZookeeper      : Starting ZK Curator
[           main] o.a.s.s.o.a.c.f.i.CuratorFrameworkImpl   : Starting
[           main] o.a.s.s.org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper   : Initiating client connection, connectString=localhost:2000/storm sessionTimeout=20000 watcher=org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.curator.ConnectionState@4bcaa195
[           main] o.a.s.s.o.a.c.f.i.CuratorFrameworkImpl   : Default schema
[localhost:2000)] o.a.s.s.org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn  : Opening socket connection to server localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:2000. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
[           main] o.a.storm.zookeeper.ClientZookeeper      : Starting ZK Curator
[           main] o.a.s.s.o.a.c.f.i.CuratorFrameworkImpl   : Starting
[.0/0.0.0.0:2000] o.a.s.s.o.a.z.s.NIOServerCnxnFactory     : Accepted socket connection from /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:63756
[           main] o.a.s.s.org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper   : Initiating client connection, connectString=localhost:2000/storm sessionTimeout=20000 watcher=org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.curator.ConnectionState@6bc24e72
[localhost:2000)] o.a.s.s.org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn  : Socket connection established to localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:2000, initiating session
[.0/0.0.0.0:2000] o.a.s.s.o.a.z.server.ZooKeeperServer     : Client attempting to establish new session at /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:63756
[           main] o.a.s.s.o.a.c.f.i.CuratorFrameworkImpl   : Default schema
[localhost:2000)] o.a.s.s.org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn  : Session establishment complete on server localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:2000, sessionid = 0x100166ad36d0001, negotiated timeout = 20000
[   SyncThread:0] o.a.s.s.o.a.z.server.ZooKeeperServer     : Established session 0x100166ad36d0001 with negotiated timeout 20000 for client /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:63756
[localhost:2000)] o.a.s.s.org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn  : Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2000. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
[ain-EventThread] o.a.s.s.o.a.c.f.s.ConnectionStateManager : State change: CONNECTED
[localhost:2000)] o.a.s.s.org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn  : Socket connection established to localhost/127.0.0.1:2000, initiating session
[.0/0.0.0.0:2000] o.a.s.s.o.a.z.s.NIOServerCnxnFactory     : Accepted socket connection from /127.0.0.1:63759
[.0/0.0.0.0:2000] o.a.s.s.o.a.z.server.ZooKeeperServer     : Client attempting to establish new session at /127.0.0.1:63759
[   SyncThread:0] o.a.s.s.o.a.z.server.ZooKeeperServer     : Established session 0x100166ad36d0002 with negotiated timeout 20000 for client /127.0.0.1:63759
[localhost:2000)] o.a.s.s.org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn  : Session establishment complete on server localhost/127.0.0.1:2000, sessionid = 0x100166ad36d0002, negotiated timeout = 20000
[ain-EventThread] o.a.s.s.o.a.c.f.s.ConnectionStateManager : State change: CONNECTED
[           main] o.a.storm.validation.ConfigValidation    : task.heartbeat.frequency.secs is a deprecated config please see class org.apache.storm.Config.TASK_HEARTBEAT_FREQUENCY_SECS for more information.
```

Comment: Could you post your topology submission code? Also which Storm version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Your main method does this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext springContext = SpringApplication.run(CurrencyStrengthCalculatorApplication.class, args);
        StormTopology topology = SpringBasedTopologyBuilder.getInstance().buildStormTopologyUsingApplicationContext(springContext);
        LOG.info("Topology created successfully. Now starting it .............");
        new LocalCluster().submitTopology("forext-topology", ImmutableMap.of(), topology);
    }
```

`submitTopology` isn't a blocking call, it just submits the topology and returns. If you want to keep the program running for a while, you need to put in a sleep after the submit. Once the main method returns, the LocalCluster will begin shutting down.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When I had just one bolt CassandraWriterBolt, topology never went down before I myself stopped. It just started happening when I added new Bolts which extend BaseCassandraBolt. I have another application, in which we submit topology in LocalCluster in exactly same way and that works perfectly fine for hours and hours.

Comment: Ok, then I'm not sure. Your logs aren't showing anything about why the topology is being shut down. You might be able to enable debug logging for the Slot class, and use this log line to debug why the topology is being shut down https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/357df98180fe368efa9e5195c4fa38670ae64a9f/storm-server/src/main/java/org/apache/storm/daemon/supervisor/Slot.java#L283